# Disable JQMIGRATE in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have been trying to disable JQMIGRATE but everything I have tried has not worked. I have followed the instructions present within the jquery folder in Magento 2.

But its still showing as Active. I have in Magento

- Reindex
- Cache
- Static:content:deploy

But its not disabled. Could this be a browser or Magento issue.

Comment: You can show me the way how you disable jqmigrate?

Comment: try my solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200340/58578

Answer (score 5):

I followed kind of like the same path as @thaddeusmt but I only added things at a custom `requirejs-config.js` file:

```js
require(['jquery'], function(jQuery) {
    jQuery.migrateMute = true;
});

var config = {};
```

Comment: This seems the least intrusive or destructive method. Too bad the `init` shim doesn't work on loading jquery, because that would be the ideal solution

Comment: Many thanks for this Jisse

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding the core `jquery-migrate` in our theme so I could set the `migrateMute` option.

In my theme `require-jsconfig.js` I set this override:

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    // disable jQuery migrate console output
    'jquery/jquery-migrate': 'js/jquery-migrate'
  }
}
```

Then copied the code `jquery-migrate.js` file to the theme `js` directory, and added this line towards the top:

```
// Set to true to prevent console output; migrateWarnings still maintained
jQuery.migrateMute = true;
```

Comment: We are also seeingthis in M2.3.1. : is this still the proposed solution? (vanilla install)

Comment: @thaddeusmt, by doing this, Jqmigrate will remove from the site or it just not visible in the console