# How to disable JQMigrate Logging

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, jquery

We keep receiving this log and stack trace from JQMigrate, but it seems to just be a warning. Is there a way to just straight up disable logging in production?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up overriding the core `jquery-migrate` in our theme so I could set the `migrateMute` option.

In my theme `require-jsconfig.js` I set this override:

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    // disable jQuery migrate console output
    'jquery/jquery-migrate': 'js/jquery-migrate'
  }
}
```

Then copied the code `jquery-migrate.js` file to the theme `js` directory, and added this line towards the top:

```
// Set to true to prevent console output; migrateWarnings still maintained
jQuery.migrateMute = true;
```

Comment: Going to mark this as the selected answer, as it's a bit cleaner than the first method that was given.

Comment: This helped, but didn't hide everything for me; I also had to include `jQuery.migrateTrace = false;`

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292260/36253 -> this is actually much cleaner solution

Answer (score 22):

One should mute `jquery.migrate` before it gets initialised.

**js/mute-migrate.js**

```
requirejs(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $.migrateMute = true;
    $.migrateTrace = false;
});
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "mute-migrate":"js/mute-migrate"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery/jquery-migrate': ['jquery','mute-migrate']
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution and should be an accepted answer

Comment: This worked instantly for me!

Comment: For more control over the load order, add this: 

  'mute-migrate': {
   deps: ['jquery']
  },

to the shim.

Answer (score 9):

In order not to overwrite any magento core files I just created a javascript file with this code

```
require(
    ['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        $.migrateMute = true;
        $.migrateTrace = false;
    }
);
```

I included the file in the head in default.xml

```
<link src="js/disable-jquery-migrate-warnings.js" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit hacky way but it works. You can create `requirejs-config.js` file in your theme and reassign `jquery-migrate` to an empty file

Example:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'jquery/jquery-migrate': 'js/empty'
    },
};
```

and create empty file `js/empty.js`

Comment: This works and I'll mark as accepted since its the only solution thats been offered, but I'd rather avoid having to make the request for the file at all if it's not going to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it without any additional scripts and just using RequireJS config:

```
var config = {
    shim: {
       'jquery/jquery-migrate': {
            init: function () {
                jQuery.migrateMute = true;
                jQuery.migrateTrace = false; // if needed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted by @thaddeusmt works great but I found an even better one.
If you already have a js file you include everywhere, you can just add this to the top:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.migrateMute = true;
});
```

so it looks something like this:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.migrateMute = true;
});
// the rest of the js file...
require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/translate",
    "domReady!",
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal"
], function ($) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick question : In the case that you have already a bought theme, which will be the best or ideal location to do the override?
I have a path like app/code/MGS/ClaueTheme/view/frontend/require-config.js  !!